# check if "text/ng-template" exists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-template

I am writing a little tool for which i need to check if a certain ng-template is defined.
All my templates are defined like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="example.html">...</script>
```

So checking if the file exists via $http won't work for me.
How can i check if said template was defined?
The only option i see so far is checking the DOM:

```
if(angular.element.find('script#example.html').length > 0) { ...
```

... but i'd realy love a better solution that does not need to check the DOM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Script directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) puts template content in [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) (source [ref.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/8f05ca555285da6e58e50dfe751426d999b0f28e/src/ng/directive/script.js#L45)) if it's a template. It means that you should be able to check if template exists by checking its presence in the cache:

```
if ($templateCache.get('example.html')) {
    // template is on the page
}
```

Comment: If i use `$templateCache.get('example.html')`  it will try to load 'example.html' from the current url and then throw an error. It will not return false or null.

Comment: No, it will check if template is cached, and return cached HTML if it's in cache. Otherwise it will return `undefined`. `$templateCache.get` will not load anything ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/cacheFactory.js#L345)).